# Apache HTTP to HTTPS redirection rule

Tags: ssl

I am trying to apply SSL to a staging server.

At the moment, we already have an ssl installed by an "unknown" guy in the production server.

While going through prd server's apache settings, I found this in

```
<VirtualHost *:80> section

RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [NC,R,L]
```

It seems like redirection rule to HTTPS but I want to understand what this means fully.
What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that whatever comes to `http://WHATEVERDOMAIN/WHATEVERPATH` will be redirected to `https://WHATEVERDOMAIN/WHATEVERPATH`.